# Ruby sort by boolean and number

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, boolean

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7.  I have the following array of hashes.  I need to sort by the boolean value first, but those results must be ordered as well in the original order.  I basically need to shift all the true hashes to the top of the array but maintain the original ordering.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
array = [{:id => 1, :accepts => false}, 
         {:id => 2, :accepts => false}, 
         {:id => 3, :accepts => true}, 
         {:id => 4, :accepts => false}, 
         {:id => 5, :accepts => true}]

sorted = array.sort do |x, y|
  if x[:accepts] == y[:accepts]
    0
  elsif x[:accepts] == true
    -1
  elsif x[:accepts] == false
    1
  end
end
```

This sort that I have yields:

5 - true
3 - true
2 - false
4 - false
1 - false

I need it to yield:

3 - true
5 - true
1 - false
2 - false
4 - false

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This does the job:

```
array.sort{|a,b| (a[:accepts] == b[:accepts]) ? ((a[:id] < b[:id]) ? -1 : 1) : (a[:accepts] ? -1 : 1)}
```

Comment: Bingo!  Thanks a million Philip!

Comment: I don't like this solution because it does NOT keep original order which was mentioned by author as an requirement. It instead implies that `:id` is already ordered and misuses this as a helper key.

Comment: Maybe this was a requirement set because he was used to another language. The Ruby Array class doesn't know operations that can change an elements position. IMHO sticking to the build-in functions is an important thing when using Ruby because it saves performance. (Especially with MRI.) But the code does not imply pre-ordering, try it out with irb.

Comment: @hurikhan77 Oh I get your point. Still, it's quite simple code.

Comment: @Philip I had an idea of solving this without sorting, after understanding that the OP probably didn't want to sort but really split and merge. The `:id` seems to be a helper key, no more. Look my answer below (wondering why it was downvoted without giving reason).

Comment: I don't know either, I find your solution quite interesting... But I gave you a vote up to neutralize ;)

Comment: The ID field really is just acting like a helper.  When I build out my array of hashes I just assign the index to each element for sorting purposes, it doesn't really hurt anything though.

Comment: could do `a[:id] <=> b[:id]`

Answer (score 17):

Use `sort_by` for these things, not `sort`!

```
array.sort_by {|h| [h[:accepts] ? 0 : 1,h[:id]]}
```

Comment: @Nakilon, On my box and using MRI 1.8.7, glenn's code takes a bit less than half the time of your code.

Comment: I'm not saying there aren't cases where `sort` is faster than `sort_by`, but I've never encountered one myself. Usually `sort_by` is significantly faster. And even more importantly, writing a function that produces a unary sort-value is *always* cleaner and clearer than a bunch of binary comparison cases. Personally, I reserve `sort` for cases where I actually need to do different *logic* according to pair traits of the comparees. Like if I need to compare strings numerically if they are both numbers, or datewise if they're both dates, or stringwise otherwise...

Answer (score 1):

```
array = [{:id => 1, :accepts => false}, 
         {:id => 2, :accepts => false}, 
         {:id => 3, :accepts => true}, 
         {:id => 4, :accepts => false}, 
         {:id => 5, :accepts => true}]

sorted = array.sort do |x, y|
  if x[:accepts] ^ y[:accepts]
      x[:accepts] ? -1 : 1
  else
      x[:id] <=> y[:id]
  end
end

puts sorted
```

Or `!=` instead of `^`, if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Well, from your question I deduce you really wanted to group the results by the `:accepts` value and merge both result sets back into one array. My solution to this would've been:

```
array.select {|where| where[:accepts] } | array.reject {|where| where[:accepts] }
# => [{:accepts=>true, :id=>3},
#     {:accepts=>true, :id=>5},
#     {:accepts=>false, :id=>1},
#     {:accepts=>false, :id=>2},
#     {:accepts=>false, :id=>4}]
```

This will maintain original order without implying any sorts on the `:id` key. This means you won't need a helper key to preserve order, and you can preserve order on the result regardless of the transported data.

This may also be useful (and maybe exactly what you need for further evaluations):

```
array.group_by {|where| where[:accepts] }
# => {false=>[{:accepts=>false, :id=>1},
#             {:accepts=>false, :id=>2},
#             {:accepts=>false, :id=>4}],
#      true=>[{:accepts=>true, :id=>3},
#             {:accepts=>true, :id=>5}]}
```

Again, no artificial sorts involved... `group_by` is new in 1.8.7.

*PS: If you don't want the first code snippet remove duplicates from your array, replace the bar operator with the plus operator. "|" merges two sets according to the [theory of sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory) (union) while "+" concatenates two sets (the result is not really a set but a plain array).*

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extra check on the `:id` key if `:accepts` is equal, as follows:

```
array = [{:id => 1, :accepts => false}, 
    {:id => 2, :accepts => false}, 
    {:id => 3, :accepts => true}, 
    {:id => 4, :accepts => false}, 
    {:id => 5, :accepts => true}]

sorted = array.sort do |x, y|
  if x[:accepts] == y[:accepts]
    if x[:id] == y[:id]
      0
    elsif x[:id] > y[:id]
      1
    elsif x[:id] < y[:id]
      -1
    end
  elsif x[:accepts] == true
    -1
  elsif x[:accepts] == false
    1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a.sort_by { |x| (x[:accepts] ? 0 : 99999) + x[:id] }
```

*Update*: Well, obviously this requires `x[:id].respond_to? "+"` and additionally there are restrictions on its range relative to the constants.

This is, however, the shortest and probably the fastest answer, if also obviously the most questionable.

The really important lesson is that it illustrates that one should look beyond `Array` (or whatever) and check `Enumerable` if that's in `(your object).class.ancestors`. These questions and their viewers are often after an answer to "*what should I learn about Ruby next, I suspect there are other ways*".

Regardless of whether this is a good way to sort (admittedly it's questionable) this answer suggests `#sort_by` and just *finding the docs* for `#sort_by` (it's not in Array) will teach a small but important lesson to a beginner.

Comment: That is this sort of very bad and dumb answers which just look smart. Not suitable for beginners seeking help for their first steps in a new language - especially in absence of any explanation.

Comment: In what substantive way is this downvoted answer different than @glenn mcdonald's upvoted answer?  Both answers could do with an explanation, it's true, and glenn's is a little better, but this one isn't _that_ bad.

Comment: "Very bad and dumb" is not a very collaborative comment, but objectively speaking I think this one has three identifiable flaws that make it a less-than-ideal suggestion. Most obviously, it assumes that ids don't get higher than 99999. That could easily be wrong, now or later. Second, magic values like 99999 are, in general, enemies of clarity and comprehension, and thus of maintainability. And thirdly, this version uses addition, which is functionally irrelevant, and would break if the ids later turned into strings, or negative numbers or something else.

Comment: Any of those things could be tolerated if this approach had compensating virtues, or if the alternatives had complicating constraints. But doing a two-item array instead of adding the two numbers is just plainly clearer. Does that make sense? (And just to be clear, I didn't downvote this, I'm just trying to explain.)

Comment: @glenn actually I wrote "sort of" but point taken. +1... And since explanation was added, voting changed

Answer (score 0):

This is because sorting in Ruby 1.8.7 is not stable

- http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/1089
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_sort#Stability

All you need to do is have your sort block not return `0`:

```
sorted = array.sort do |x, y|
  if x[:accepts] == y[:accepts]
    x[:id] <=> y[:id]  # not 0
  elsif x[:accepts]
    -1
  else
    1
  end
end
```

(no need to explicitly compare a boolean to `true` and `false`)